# What is wrong with this application of Ax-Kochen?

Tags: model-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I have been bashing my head for a couple of hours trying to find out what's wrong with the following argument: 
Let $K=\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p-1})$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}_p((-p)^{1/p-1})$. These are two totally ramified extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ such that $(vK,vp)\cong(vL,vp)\cong (\frac{1}{p-1}\mathbb{Z},1)$. By Ax-Kochen for finitely ramified henselian fields (see e.g. Theorem on pg. 26 here http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~zoe/GTM/MT.pdf), this should imply that $K\equiv L$ in the language of rings. In particular, $K$ contains an element $\beta$ such that $\beta^{p-1}=-p$. If we let $\alpha$ be the $p-1$-th root of $p$ in $K$, then $(\alpha/\beta)^{p-1}=\frac{p}{-p}=-1$. But since the residue field of $K$ is $\mathbb{F}_p$, there is no solution to the equation $x^{p-1}=-1$ in $K$. What has gone wrong?

Comment: I’m not sure what “$K\equiv L$ in the language of rings” means. It certainly does *not* mean that the two rings are isomorphic, as the example $p=3$ shows: one field contains the cube roots of unity, the other doesn’t.

Comment: @Lubin Note the [model-theory] tag. ≡ is the standard notation for [elementary equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence).

Comment: I'm a total noob in model theory, but since there must be something wrong I naturally wonder if the sentence "there exists $\beta$ such that $\beta ^{p-1}=-p$" is literally preserved under such an equivalence, or could the $-p$ be turned into a $p$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, this equivalence means that they satisfy the same sentences in the language of rings. One such sentence is $\exists x(x^{p-1}=-p)$. I suspect that the version of this Theorem in the link that I quoted might be wrong but I am not 100% sure yet.

Comment: I guess the question then is whether $p$ itself is describable or definable in the language of rings.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, so let me clarify. The language of rings is $L_r:=\{+,\cdot,0,1\}$; this means that one is allowed to form sentences using the symbols of $L_r$ together with the usual quantifiers and conjunctions/disjunctions. Formally, the sentence that I wrote above would be $\exists x(x^{p-1}+1+1+1...+1)=0$, where the symbol $1$ is written $p$ times.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. All I know is that your argument that something has gone wrong is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think the AKE theorem you quote should be for unramified rather than finitely ramified henselian fields of mixed characteristic. The versions of AKE for finitely ramified mixed characteristic that I know (e.g. Basarab) require elementary equivalence of all the residue rings, not just the residue field. Note that for finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, elementary equivalence implies isomorphism, as the valuation ring and the residue rings are all definable. Also Prestel-Roquette state their completeness of p-adically closed fields only for the unramified case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1378173)

Comment: @Saad Actually, I think this does provide a complete answer to the question.